# Connect python to oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have installed oracle client and oracle client-dev, and setup ORACLE_HOME environment variable. Yet when I attempt to install tux_oracle (python setup.py build) I get the following:
fatal error: oci.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 6):

Well, the answer is to install cx_Oracle not tx_Oracle. The way to do it in Ubuntu is the following:

1. You must have the oracle client installed in your PC. If not download from oracle http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxsoft-082809.html.
2. Install alien in your PC to be able to convert rpm to deb:

```
sudo apt-get -i alien
```

3. Convert the rpm to deb:

```
sudo alien -d oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.2.0.i386.rpm
```

4. Install

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i oracle-instantclient11.2-basic_11.2.0.2.0-2_i386.deb
   ```
5. Set ORACLE_HOME environment variable in /etc/profile.d by creating a file oracle.sh which must contain:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client
source oracle.sh
```

6. Update LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
sudo vi /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf which must contain:  
"$ORACLE_HOME/lib"
sudo ldconfig
```

7. Download and install cx_Oracle (depending on the version of oracle and python you are using) from http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/
   Again convert rpm to deb using alien and install:

```
sudo alien -d cx_Oracle-5.1-11g-py32-1.i386.rpm
sudo dpkg -i cx-oracle_5.1-2_i386.deb
```

8. cx_Oracle gets installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/. You must do:
   sudo mv site-packages/cx_Oracle* dist-packages/
   sudo rmdir site-packages/
   sudo ln -s dist-packages site-packages

Now you should have no problem connecting to oracle.
From python type:

```
import cx_Oracle
```

To connect to the database specify a connection string in tsnames.ora or directly:

```
connection_string = 'username/password@(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA= (SID=MY_SID)))'
```

Comment: is installing cx_oracle similar on x64 python/os?

Answer (score 1):

I am using [cx_oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/) to connect to my Oracle database. Did you give it a try?

Answer (score 1):

That header file can be found in the development suite. For some reason, it's not included in the default distribution package. Have a look at

http://my.opera.com/onyxluo/blog/cannot-find-oci-h-in-oracle9-2-client

Here's the page content, for your convenience. I got it from Google cache as the page was down when I got there.

> The reason of this problem is because OCI (Oracle Call
>   Interface)package is not installed in Oracle9.2 client. The default
>   path of "oci.h" is $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/demo. This problem doesn't exist
>   on Oracle Database 9.2.0.1. But for Oracle 9.2.0.1 client, OCI package
>   is not included in client even if you select the full package of
>   client installation.
>
> Solution:
>
> 1. install Oracle 9.2.0.1 client first.
> 2. In OUI(Oracle Universal Installer), use the same oracle home with Oracle 9.2.0.1 client, and then select Oracle Database install.
> 3. Choose Customized in database installation
> 4. Uncheck Enterprise Manager and Oracle Database and others except OCI and OCCI.
>
> After OCI installed, $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/demo will contain oci.h and
>   other *.h files.